# Remove or don't write last ';' symbol in the row

Tags: c#, csv, export

Well I have export to CSV script.

I export list of struct. I write with help of StringWriter. In struct field array foreach cycle I iterate through all properties and after every property I put ';'. In the end of line I put WriteLine().

So as output I have:

```
value1;value2;value3;
```

And I want:

```
value1;value2;value3
```

The question is : how to get what I want from what I get, or based on what I'v already made.

I have 3 ideas right now:

1. The last 2 symbols in line should be something like ";\r(\n)" So replace this combination with nothing.
2. Check if the property is last.
3. Trim last(before newline) symbol in each row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use String.Join to form each line for your output.  It prevents you from having to check which term is last.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx

```
var values = { "value1", "value2", "value3" };

string line = string.Join(";", values);
```

line will be

```
"value1;value2;value3"
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code,

```
str.TrimEnd(';');
```

Comment: Not bad, but problematic for large strings since it incurs a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I just delete the last character after the line is formed.

Comment: -1 - Deleting last character will create the whole string again, it is better to use `string.Join()`

Comment: StringBuilder does not create the whole string again, but your solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

I use a `StringBuilder` and just do:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
// ...
// add the text
// ...
builder.Length--;
```

This way I can avoid the string copy.